Flutter iOS build fails with "UIApplication does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'" error in url_launcher_ios
I'm getting a build error when trying to run my Flutter app on iOS simulator. The error seems to be related to the url_launcher_ios plugin.
Error Message:
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.2.4/ios/Classes/Launcher.swift:20:1: error: type 'UIApplication' does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'
extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
^
UIKit.UIApplication:24:15: note: candidate has non-matching type '(URL, [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any], (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?) -> Void'
open func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)? = nil)

What I've tried:
Updated Podfile to use iOS 12.0:
platform :ios, '12.0'

Cleaned and reinstalled dependencies:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod install

pubspec.yaml dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^6.2.4

My Question:*
I have recently updated the Simulator to 18.1 iPhone 16 Plus and these different errors started to pop up a previous error was:
suggests that the build process for your iOS app
in Xcode failed, and the main issue seems to be
that certain Flutter dependencies (e.g., sqflite)
are unable to locate Flutter.h

What is the reason for finding this error and how can I fix it?
this is the full error
Writing result bundle at path:
    /var/folders/cd/yh1682_95jz__1z337mbc0dh0000gp/T/flutter_tools.KNaYLQ/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir1iOiMu/temporary_xcresult_bundle

/Users/User/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.2.4/ios/Classes/Launcher.swift:20:1: error: type 'UIApplication' does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'
extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
^
UIKit.UIApplication:24:15: note: candidate has non-matching type '(URL, [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any], (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?) -> Void'
    open func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
              ^
/Users/User/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.2.4/ios/Classes/Launcher.swift:20:1: note: add stubs for conformance
extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
^

/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'path_provider_foundation-path_provider_foundation_privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'image_picker_ios-image_picker_ios_privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_foundation-shared_preferences_foundation_privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'url_launcher_ios-url_launcher_ios_privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'google_mobile_ads-google_mobile_ads' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'url_launcher_ios' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_foundation' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'path_provider_foundation' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'flutter_inappwebview' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'image_picker_ios' from project 'Pods')

note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' from project 'Pods')
/Users/User/StudioProjects/Project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 18.1.99. (in target 'GoogleUserMessagingPlatform' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Plus.

If anything is unclear or need more code snippets please let me know
This is the only project that is not working other projects simulator is working

Was this something that was investigated here?

Is this new project, or something that worked in Xcode 15?

@benc old project that was working and stopped working with the new updates

it looks like you have a lot of errors... maybe supported deployment target versions is enforced more strictly now? That's a lot of xml to edit.

I used to have this error and I fixed it by also adding the url_launcher_ios package So try importing not just url_launcher but also url_launcher_ios in your pubspec.yaml

Update your dependencies in pubspec.yml to the compatible version
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  url_launcher_ios: ^6.1.7

Run
flutter pub get

Then clean and build cache
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
flutter run


try to use latest version of 'url_launcher', then run:
$ flutter pub get
$ flutter pub upgrade
source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/155342#issuecomment-2361005231
